# Lexical scope in javascript function

Tags: javascript, scope, closures, lexical-scope

The following snippet:

```
a = 0;

function f1() {
    a = 1;
    f2();
}

function f2() {
    return a;
}

f1();
```

returns undefined.

From what I understand, functions get access to variables when they're defined, and access the values of those variables when they're being executed. So, in this case I would've guessed f2 to have access to the global variable 'a', and read it's modified value (1). So why is it undefined?

Comment: The `return` in `f2` does not return from `f1`… But yes, all three `a`s refer to the same global variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not returning the result of the invocation of `f2()`, or anything else, in the `f1` function, so `f1` is correctly returning `undefined`.

Comment: good catch! The function gets the value returned by its body, but it still has to return that to its caller.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you were after was the following:

```
a = 0; // variable a defined in the global scope and set to 0

function f1() {
    a = 1; // since a is declared without var,
           // sets the value of global variable a to 1
    return f2();
}

function f2() {
    return a; // since a was not declared with var,
              // return a from the global scope
}

alert(f1()); // displays the computed value 1 of a
```

Regards.